# Сбрасывается итератор pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

В чём отличие между:

**Варианта A**

```
driver = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host)
cursor = driver['my-collection']['service-execution-log'].find()
for item in cursor:
    print(item)
```

**Вариант B**

```
driver = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host)
for item in driver['my-collection']['service-execution-log'].find():
    print(item)
```

В первом случае оказывается курсор пустым. Во втором случае -- нет.

---

```
import pymongo

mongodb_host = '0.0.0.0'

driver = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host)
cursor = driver['market-radar-status']['service-execution-log'].find()
print('y')
for item in cursor:
    print(item)


driver = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host)
print('x')
for item in driver['market-radar-status']['service-execution-log'].find():
    print(item)
```

Если запустить данный код в дебаггере и выполнить построчно, то проблема воспроизведётся. Видимо, затык с таймаутами

Comment: @MaxU простите, я был пьян и не ведал. Что пишу

Comment: как вы получаете `self.db` в обоих случаях?

Comment: вы уверены, что вы не используете один и тот же курсор, который может "выдохнуться" (`exhausted cursor`)?

Comment: @MaxU Воспроизведите код

Comment: @MaxU я даже могу докерфайл для монги, если он упростит воспроизведение, а также сделать код для вставки в коллекцию.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а `close()` вы вообще не пользуетесь?

Comment: @0xdb а как это связано, если даже итерирования не начинается? Курсор пустой

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что бага не воспроизводится и вопрос не имеет смысла

Answer (score 1):

Не получается воспроизвести данное поведение:

**Варианта A**

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

---

```
In [22]: cursor = client["test_db"]["test"].find()

In [23]: for item in cursor:
    ...:     print(item)
    ...:
{'_id': ObjectId('5d716a73dcbe6f3064d0d497'), 'key': 'val'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5d716a91dcbe6f3064d0d498'), 'list': ['string1', 'string2']}
```

**Варианта B**

```
In [24]: for item in client["test_db"]["test"].find():
    ...:     print(item)
    ...:
{'_id': ObjectId('5d716a73dcbe6f3064d0d497'), 'key': 'val'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5d716a91dcbe6f3064d0d498'), 'list': ['string1', 'string2']}
```

Comment: Очень странно. Не понимаю

Comment: Запустите в дебаггере и выполните построчно

Comment: @hedgehogues, других требований не будет? ;)